# Intl.NumberFormat no agrega separador de miles a números de 4 dígitos

Tags: javascript, internacionalización

Necesito dar formato de moneda `CLP` mediante `JavaScript`.

He estado intentando hacerlo así:

```
new Intl.NumberFormat('es-CL', {currency: 'CLP', style: 'currency'}).format(1000)
```

Pero este enfoque tiene un problema ya conocido por la internacionalización donde obvian el uso de separador de miles para números de 4 dígitos.

¿Existe alguna forma efectiva para la manipulación de currencies en Chile?

El esperado es:

```
$1
$10
$100
$1.000
$10.000
$100.000
$1.000.000
```

...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La API [Intl](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl) de Javascript para las [configuraciones de localización](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl#locales_argument) utiliza la información establecida por el [Unicode Common Locale Data Repository](http://cldr.unicode.org/) (*CLDR*)

Actualmente el CLDR ha establecido para el [sistema numérico](http://cldr.unicode.org/translation/-core-data/numbering-systems) en [español](https://st.unicode.org/cldr-apps/v#/es/Symbols/70ef5e0c9d323e01) que los *"dígitos mínimos para agrupar"* es igual a 2.

> The minimumGroupingDigits determines what the default for a locale is. In this case the value should be "2" to illustrate that the separator only appears once the number of thousands goes into the double-digits (i.e. 10 thousand or above) and not for single-digit thousands (i.e. anything below 10 thousand).
>
> ---
>
> El `minimumGroupingDigits` determina cuál es el valor predeterminado para una configuración regional. En este caso, el valor debe ser `"2"` para ilustrar que el separador solo aparece una vez que el número de miles entra en dos dígitos (es decir, 10 mil o más) y no para miles de un solo dígito (es decir, cualquier cosa por debajo de 10 mil).

#### Demo:

```js
let formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat('es-CL', {
  style: 'currency',
  currency: 'CLP'
})

console.log(formatter.format(1));
console.log(formatter.format(10));
console.log(formatter.format(100));
console.log(formatter.format(1000), ' <- ACA el problema');
console.log(formatter.format(10000));
console.log(formatter.format(100000));
console.log(formatter.format(1000000));
```

---

Con respecto a:

> [...] obvian el uso de separador de miles para números de 4 dígitos.
> ¿Existe alguna forma efectiva para la manipulación de currencies en Chile?

Podrías *"parchar"* (*sobrescribir*) el método `format`.

#### Ejemplo:

```js
// @START HACKING
(function() {

  // Obtenemos la definicion de la funcion original
  let prop = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Intl.NumberFormat.prototype, 'format');

  // Sobrescribimos el método "format"
  Object.defineProperty(Intl.NumberFormat.prototype, 'format', {
    get: function() {
      return function(value) {
        let fn = prop.get.call(this), // Recuperamos la funcion "formateadora" original 
          opts = this.resolvedOptions(); // Obtenemos las opciones de "formateo"
        
        // Solo cambiamos el formateo cuando es moneda en español y el numero es >= 1.000 o menor a 10.000
        if (opts.style == 'currency' && opts.locale.substr(0, 2) == 'es' && opts.numberingSystem == 'latn' && value >= 1000 && value < 10000) {
          let num = fn(10000), // -> [pre]10[sep]000[sub]
            pre = num.substr(0, num.indexOf('10')),
            sep = num.substr(num.indexOf('10') + 2, 1),
            sub = num.substr(num.indexOf('000') + 3);
          num = value.toString();
          return pre + num.slice(0, 1) + sep + num.slice(1) + sub;
        }
        // Sino devolvemos el número formateado normalmente
        return fn(value);
      };
    },
  });
})();

// @USE

let formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat('es-CL', {
  style: 'currency',
  currency: 'CLP'
})

console.log(formatter.format(1));
console.log(formatter.format(10));
console.log(formatter.format(100));
console.log(formatter.format(1000), ' <- ACA ahora funciona');
console.log(formatter.format(10000));

formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat('es-CL', {
  style: 'currency',
  currency: 'ARS'
})

console.log(formatter.format(1));
console.log(formatter.format(10));
console.log(formatter.format(100));
console.log(formatter.format(1000), ' <- ACA tambien funciona');
console.log(formatter.format(10000));
```

Comment: Lleve el código a un codesandbox y falla :/ https://codesandbox.io/s/gracious-wozniak-c0sk7?file=/src/index.js

Comment: No sabría que decirte, acabo de entrar y [veo que funciona](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xsKlV.png). PD: no se como funciona `Codesandbox`.

Comment: Toda la razón, entre nuevamente y esta funcionando... al parecer es algo de codesandbox que bloquea hacer override "en vivo" del prototype.

Answer (score 0):

A la respuesta publicada arriba, va bien, pero si quieres tener decimales, yo le he cambiado la linea:

```
return pre + num.slice(0, 1) + sep + num.slice(1) + sub;
```

Por:

```
return pre + num.slice(0, 1) + sep + num.slice(1).replace(".", ",") + sub;
```